# Стоит ли переходить на обучение Java 10?

Tags: java, java-8

Стоит ли бросать Java 8 и продолжать свое обучение с Java 10? Тем более, как я слышал, они рассматривают идею перейти на полугодовой график релизов Java.

Comment: Нормально тут минуса летят за вопрос который более чем волнует любого новичка

Comment: Проблема в формулировке вопроса, из-за которой вопрос годится на закрытие по причине "необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ". Каждый сам для себя определяет, стоит ли. Вот если бы вы спросили про ключевые отличия Java 8 и 10, или что-то другое объективное - было бы совсем другое дело.

Comment: @Regent Написал бы про ключевые отличия его бы точно так же заминусовали! Типа куча статей вышло читай в гугле

Comment: Закрывать не стоит, автор прав, это один из вопросов, которыми интересуются новички и да, есть такая тревога как написал @Regent, у самого рука тянулась на кнопку нажать, но взвесив все, подумал, что вопрос представляет определенную ценность. Уже даже ответ есть. На плюс не заслуживает, но и минусами сыпать не стоит.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Что значит всё бросать? Все версии Java сохраняют обратную совместимость, каждая новая только добавляет некоторое количество возможностей. Описание разницы между Java 8 и Java 10 уместится на пару страничек текста, а учебники по Java 2 всё ещё актуальны.

На полугодовой график релизов уже год как перешли. Java 9 была в сентябре 2017-го.